# ¿Cómo generar tablas dinámicas y gráficos en Excel de forma automática usando VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en **Excel**, para esto desarrollé un código que me permite abrir múltiples archivos, extraer información de esos documentos y recopilarla en una hoja **Sheet1**.

A partir de estos datos en **Sheet1** debo generar tablas dinámicas y gráficos, para lo cual primero convertí mis datos en una tabla y manualmente creé las tablas dinámicas y los gráficos, anexando una línea de código para que las tablas se actualicen automáticamente cuando mi **Sheet1** cambie, sin embargo las tablas dinámicas y por ende los gráficos no están actualizándose automáticamente.

Si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho, soy nueva en **VBA**.
El siguiente es el código que estoy usando para convertir mis datos en una tabla y las últimas líneas son para refrescar automáticamente las tablas dinámicas.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateTable()
    Dim src As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set src = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=src, _
    xlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes, tablestyleName:="TableStyleMedium28").Name = "DataBase"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

Comment: Te da algún tipo de error el código? si es así, dónde te da error?

Comment: Por otro lado, para hacer un rango dinámico para la tabla dinámica, mejor que hacer una formula es ir a Fórmulas->Nombres. Creas uno nuevo y lo llamas como quieras, ahora su referencia sería esta fórmula (supongamos que los datos comienzan en la celda A1 y la hoja en la que están se llama BBDD): `=DESREF(BBDD!$A$1;0;0;CONTARA(BBDD!$A:$A);CONTARA(BBDD!$1:$1))`. Adaptando esa fórmula tendrías solucionado que la tabla dinámica crezca con tus datos.

Comment: No me da ningún error solo que la tabla dinámica no se actualiza sola, debo darle clic derecho y actualizar y solo de esa manera me da los nuevos datos.

Comment: Donde debería poner ese ejemplo de formula que me has dado?

Answer (score 2):

Para poder hacer un rango dinámico para la tabla dinámica debes ir a la pestaña Fórmulas y en el botón Administrar Nombres:

[image: Nombres]

Una vez dentro, creas un nombre nuevo y lo nombras como desees, y le pones la fórmula:

[image: Nuevo Nombre]

Por último vas al origen de datos de tu tabla dinámica y pones el nombre que le hayas dado.

Por otro lado, para que los datos se actualicen automáticamente, deberás poner el código en el objeto hoja donde se almacenen los datos, de lo contrario los cambios en dicha hoja no provocarán la actualización. No obstante esto puede volverse engorroso si se ponen datos a mano.
[image: ModuloHoja]

Comment: Muy importante indicar por qué es engorroso si se ponen datos a mano. Podría poner un botón que lance la actualización si ese es el caso (porque de lo contrario será una edición muy lenta)

Comment: Correcto, a cada celda que se cambie, se ejecutaría la actualización. Una base de datos pequeña no impactaría, pero si la base de datos es grande el proceso de actualizar la tabla dinámica se ralentizaría cada vez más...

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo con la información que has puesto, copias valores de algún sitio, los pegas en otro, y quieres que tu tabla dinámica se actualice.

En ese caso lo mejor quizás sea tirar de una plantilla, con una tabla que ya esté vinculada a una tabla dinámica existente.

Yo he creado un archivo con 3 hojas:

1. TABLA DINÁMICA: Donde está mi tabla dinámica
2. TABLA: Donde está el objeto Tabla, que alimenta a mi tabla dinámica
3. DATOS NUEVOS: De donde cojo los datos nuevos para copiar y pegar en la hoja TABLA

Mi tabla original y mi tabla dinàmica original son así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero borrar lo que hay y poner estos datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que he usado es:

```
Sub Macro1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim MiTabla As ListObject
Set MiTabla = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabla").ListObjects("Tabla1")


If MiTabla.ListRows.Count > 0 Then MiTabla.DataBodyRange.Delete 'borramos lo que hubiera

'<----aquí pondrías el código necesario para traer los nuevos datos de donde fuera, y pegarlos en la tabla--->
'en mi caso, los cojo de la hoja DATOS NUEVOS, pero cambia esta parte por lo tuyo

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATOS NUEVOS").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Copy

'<----aquí termina el código necesario para traer los nuevos datos de donde fuera, y pegarlos en la tabla--->

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TABLA").Range("a2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'los pegamos a partir de la primera fila de la tabla
DoEvents 'si tienes muchos datos, es mejor usarlo para garantizar el pegado

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
DoEvents 'para garantizar que todo se refresque

Set MiTabla = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'refrescamos

End Sub
```

Como verás, refresco en la propia macro en vez de hacerlo desde un evento, porque al hacerlo desde el evento, este se activa cada vez que cambias una celda, con lo que si pegas, por ejemplo, información de 100 celdas, se activa 100 veces.

Se puede evitar con un `Application.EnableEvents=False` pero creo que es complicarse la vida. Creo que es más fácil así, aunque desconozco tu situación.

Tras ejecutar el código, mi tabla y mi tabla dinámica están así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver, los datos se han actualizado.

La ventaja de este método es que el código es más sencillo, porque la tabla y la tabla dinámica ya están vinculadas. No hay que complicarse con nombres ni crear nuevos objetos ni nada.

Dejo un ejemplo en Google Drive por si ayuda: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QVrcX6f6jc7ovChALSdMGiCl-Zl8hgBs

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, lo probaré para ver si me funciona :)

Comment: Disculpa Elier, pero crear un nombre de referencia a un rango no es algo complejo, tu solución pasa por duplicar los datos, lo que significa duplicar el tamaño del fichero. Eso no es eficiente, lo ideal siempre es intentar reducir al mínimo el peso de los ficheros para que funcionen lo más fluido posible.

Comment: Hola @Damian, no puse complejo, dije complicarse. ¿Para qué hacer más cosas de las necesarias? Y segundo, lo de duplicar datos, sí, en mi ejemplo simplemente dupliqué datos como ejemplo sencillo, pero no tiene nada que ver con la utilidad del código. En su pregunta la OP especificó que ya tiene código para *abrir múltiples archivos, extraer información de esos documentos y recopilarla en una hoja*, que en mi ejemplo se llama DATOS NUEVOS. Y de ahí se lo quiere llevar a una tabla y actualizar una tabla dinámica y gráficos, que es exactamente lo que hace mi código.